# Unit testing ASP.NET MVC 3 Restful Service without a webserver

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, rest

I am currently writing a MVC3 app that will have a restful api exposed. Basically all am doing is providing some
controller methods that return json objects instead of views and handling verbs correctly (i.e. puts posts etc).

I'm not sure how to unit test the restful api. I could just call the controllers directly in c# but this means
I am not "eating my own dog food" (it's a third party who'll be using this api). 
So currently in my unit tests I am using HttpWebRequest to create requests that hit a real web server. 
This is less than satisfactory because I now have to have a webserver running on my build machine. 
Is there another way to do this? i.e. Simulate a real web request some how that would hit all the parts of the code that would be hit if it was running in IIS?

Answer (score 2):

A unit test means testing an isolated unit of code, in your case the controllers. If you want to test the whole system end-to-end its more of an integration test.

You might be able to use the iis 7 hostable web core to set up your integration tests in your own process:

http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/host-your-own-web-server-in-your-application-using-iis-7-0-hostable-web-core.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll have a look.